# Get Solution Directory in Intel Visual Fortran

Tags: windows, visual-studio, fortran, environment-variables, intel-fortran

Is there a way within an Intel Visual Fortran project to get a string representing the Visual Studio Solution Directory?

Get_Environment_Variable doesn't seem to have that ability as far as I can tell.

Intel Fortran 2017 and VS 2015.

Comment: Mentioning GET_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE implies that you want to know the solution directory when running your program. Is that the case? If so, why?

Comment: Yes that is so. I want to so that I can easily determine a relative path on multiple user machines.

Comment: What answer do you expect on machines that don't have a copy of the solution?

Comment: Nothing. I'm not interested in that right now. No one is currently using the code not attached to visual studio. When I get to that I'll come up with a better permanent solution, but that is  several other upgrades down the road.

Comment: I was trying to highlight that there is a conceptual misunderstanding behind the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your other comments, it seems to me that you're possibly more interested in the directory containing the executable. If you know your solution directory structure you can work out the solution location from that.

You do this in two steps. First you call the Windows API routine [`GetModuleHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683199(v=vs.85).aspx), passing `NULL` as the argument. This returns a handle to the current executable. Then you pass this handle to [`GetModuleFileName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197(v=vs.85).aspx) which returns the path to the executable as a NUL-terminated string.

If you wanted to separate out just the path, you could use the Intel library routine `SPLITPATHQQ`.

Example:

```
program whereami
use kernel32
use, intrinsic :: ISO_C_BINDING
implicit none

integer(HANDLE) :: h
character(MAX_PATH) :: f
integer(DWORD) :: ret


h = GetModuleHandle (NULL)
ret = GetModuleFileName (h,f,len(f))
print *, f(1:index(f,C_NULL_CHAR)-1)
end program whereami
```

Answer (score 1):

Within the property pages for an Intel Fortran project you can use the $(SolutionDir) macro to query the solution directory.

There are a number of ways to then incorporate the value of this macro into Fortran source when it is compiled (e.g. define a preprocessor symbol on the compiler command line and then reference that preprocessor symbol in the source), or pass the value of that macro to a runtime instance of your program (e.g. through a command line argument, specified via the relevant project property) **when the program is started from within Visual Studio**.